# How to change the outline size of the RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button

I'm using `RadioButton`s for my app which seems like big and also thickness seems high. I want to know if there is a way to reduce the outline thickness?

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/statusRadioGroup"
    android:buttonTint="@color/order_inprocess"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/radioActive"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioActive"
        android:textColor="@color/order_inprocess"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        app:buttonTint="@color/order_inprocess"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="Active" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/radioDeactive"
        android:textColor="@color/order_inprocess"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        app:buttonTint="@color/order_inprocess"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="Deactive" />

</RadioGroup>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create custom drawables.

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_radio_button_checked"
    android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_radio_button_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

If you're interested in animations check out `StateListAnimator` and `AnimatedVectorDrawable`.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#ViewState

Answer (score 0):

you can't edit icon radio from android studio, you can use icon drawable from http://flaticon.com/